# unknown folder created in /etc/ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I just noticed that some unknown folder has been created in my `/etc/ansible` directory.

Here it is ,

```
monitoring-server@monitoring-server:/etc/ansible$ ls
['  ansible.cfg  hosts  java.retry  java.yml  nginx.retry  nginx.yml  roles  test.retry  test.yml
```

This `['` is the folder.

```
monitoring-server@monitoring-server:/etc/ansible$ ls -l
total 56
drw-r--r-- 3 root root  4096 Jul 27 07:12 ['
```

I need to be root to open it.

```
root@monitoring-server:/etc/ansible/['# tree
.
└── opt
    └── rsyslog']

2 directories, 0 files
```

Well, the `/opt/rsyslog` is one of the directories I made on some remote servers using ansible.

How is this folder created and Why  is it created?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I have a weird directory" is not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory tree is `['/opt/rsyslog']` – seems like you mistyped string path as list sometime ago and fed it into module with local host as target.

As long as `/etc/ansible` also seems to be your working directory (which is really weird practice), path `['` / `opt` / `rsyslog']` has been created.

You may safely remove it.